# How to Ensure that a new Trigger does not Screw up Existing Processes

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers

Background:

- We have a (very) mature legacy system that is built on an Oracle database.
- We need to add a number of triggers that on every update, insert, or delete on a set of specified tables create a record in a table called TBL_REPLICATION.
- Whatever happens, nothing should prevent the execution of existing functionality.

What I mean by this is that if, say, there is a problem writing to TBL_REPLICATION (due to contention or whatever) it would be preferable that the action of the new trigger fail and **no** record be written to TBL_REPLICATION rather than any other actions be affected.

Is there anything that we could do - either in the triggers or in the table that they will write to  - to make the writes to TBL_REPLICATION somehow *less critical* than the existing writes and reads (on the other tables)?

I realise that "less critical" is rather a nebulous term but I hope I have got the gist of what I am trying to do across.

Comment: It will be better for you to read this http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/o58asktom-101055.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'd do:

1. Place the critical table, and its indexes, on a separate tablespace, so that any storage-realated issue won't affect your "main" data. (you can go as far as placing it on a separate ASM diskgroup, but it's probably an overkill)
2. Regarding the "isolation" of the write operations to the critical table, so it won't affect (delay/raise errors) the main "logic" - 
   I'd simply use `dbms_job.submit` function in order to spawn a separate slave process, which will perform the needed action. Note that due to the fact that the operation won't be performed serially, as a part of the main flow, but basically parallel to the main flow - you can't really depend on a specific state of the base tables' data, when performing any operation on the new critical table; but, from your explanations - it doesn't seem like a problem.
3. Either way, if you choose to run all the operations on this new table in separate threads, or if you choose to run them as part of the main logic - **it's extremely important to wrap the logic in a separate PL/SQL block, where you only perform logging logic in the exception section and continue the execution (don't allow the code to crash)**. That way you'll assure that in a case of an error - it's logged, but there's no harm to the main logic, which continues to execute.

**Note**:
Remember that triggers are almost always a bad practice - it's a piece of PL/SQL code which runs after each SQL execution (which matches the trigger filter). That basically means - a context switch from SQL to PL/SQL engine, during every operating. This is highly ineffective. If you're dealing with large amounts of data - you should first try to explore some other solutions to your problem.

**Note #2**:
I'd most certainly modify the table (if it's small enough - the entire table, if it's large - the few last/relevant partitions) and its indexes, so they'd use the **Keep Cache**, instead of the Buffer Cache (you'd have to set a size for the Keep Cache first, using `db_keep_cache_size`). This way, it won't "compete" with other objects' blocks for memory and will always be cached. 
Also, I'd recommend to record the behavior (resource consumption, execution plans) of the critical SQL statements using OEM and AWR Reports before making any changes, so you can easily compare it afterwards and pinpoint the effects of the performed changes.

Those are my two cents on this matter.

Comment: @david I've added another note :)